# How can an update message from a rabbitmq broker reach all relevant clients via multiple websocket servers?

Tags: web-services, message-queue, websockets, messaging, message-passing

Lets say I have multiple websocket servers that maintain many connections to clients to send updates. These websocket servers will be pulling said updates from a rabbitmq broker, and broadcasting them to all relevant clients who happen to be on a page that needs an update.

My question is how can all clients who are on page[x] get an update for it if they are split up across multiple websocket servers? WS-server-A will recieve an update and forward it out to all its clients on page[x], but whate about the clients connected to WS-server-b who has clients on the same page?

(edited below to add more details)

The way I'm imagining this scenario is like so:

For an imaginary forum, we have a multi-threaded web server that does page rendering and responds to api calls. When someone saves a post on a topic, the web server saves the post to the db, then passes the post off to rabbitmq.

Rabbitmq forwards this post to the relevant exchange (say, 'new-posts'. There are also other exchanges: 'new-topics', 'alerts', etc), where the websocket server picks it up, examines the "header" and forwards the post to all users who are on the relevant page.

Comment: Does WS-Server-B not get the updates? Or are you asking how can B also get the updates?

Comment: @ShaneAndrie Yes, I'm asking how both can get them so that clients on page[x] connected to server-b can receive the updates they need as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What probably happens right now is that some messages are processed by server A, and never delivered to B, and some are processed by B, but A never receives them. This is because you haven't specified the exchange: the default one is the **direct exchange**, meaning that messages are sent to one of the queues at a time, using round robin.

In order for multiple servers to receive the message, you may use the **fanout exchange** routing. With this type of routing, the same message will be routed to every queue.

The exchange routing type is specified [when you create the exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html).

You can find additional information [about different types of exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) on the official RabbitMQ website.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you're talking about is best addressed using the [Pub-sub messaging pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PublishSubscribeChannel.html). In RabbitMQ this is supported by the Fanout Exchange type. Check out the [Pub-Sub tutorial on the Rabbit Website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html) for a walkthrough of creating a fanout exchange.